# Will quitting PhD after six months affect my ability to get another?

Tags: phd, interview, supervision

I've been at my current PhD for six months but in that time have only had 3 meetings with my supervisor, the last of which was over 2 months ago. Worse than that, I've tried enquiring about our next meeting but he's stopped responding to my emails. Now, I never expected to be coddled in my PhD, but what I do know is PhDs are difficult and with the complete dearth of oversight I'm receiving at the moment I am unsure if I will be able to complete my PhD effectively on my own.

Given this, I've decided that it may be time for me to start looking elsewhere for other PhD opportunities. What I worry, though, is how it will look in future applications when they see I already started a PhD and dropped out or if I even mention it at all and leave a blank on my CV for that period? Further, if I do mention it or an enquiry is made in an interview, what could I say or how could I spin it?

Will quitting a PhD after six months look bad for future PhD applications?

Comment: It almost certainly *will*, unfortunately. Is changing advisors an option?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think the funding might be attached to that supervisor, though getting a second supervisor might be an option. I'd like to speak to my supervisor about this but I think it should be done in person which is something I can't exactly do at the moment.

Comment: Do they have office hours? It's not entirely graceful, but it might be your best bet to guarantee a face-to-face meeting if they're not responding to emails at all. (That said, it's quite possible they've missed emails due to a spam filter - you might try emailing them again from a different email account.) Another thing you might want to do is talk to another one of their students: are they in general email silence? Are they known for not being accessible?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Unfortunately, they're dean of faculty and so have no office hours and I'm unable to get past their secretary without an appointment. I've received a notification from their secretary that my email was received but nothing more than this so I know it's not going into spam. I'm friends with another of their PhD students and they've made it clear he's always been like this.

Comment: I would email the secretary and - **politely** - bring up the lack of a response. This really is an unacceptable situation.

Comment: Can you speak to whoever is in charge of your graduate program (department chair, graduate coordinator, etc)?  They can tell you about the process and requirements for changing an advisor, including whether you can keep your funding.  (Note to future readers: it is a really good idea to know how this works in your program **before** you start...)  They may also be able to help mediate between you and your supervisor.

Comment: In general, yes, it will look bad. Not necessarily impossible though. One of my PhD colleagues was hired despite having quit a previous PhD, but his application came with a letter of recommendation from his former advisor explaining how he basically had not had enough time to properly tutor him, how their research interests didn't really align, that he was a great researcher and would fit much better in the new programme. But this was very much an edge case...

Comment: Thank you, all for the advice. I feel like I have some concrete steps I can take now.

Comment: You need to change advisers within the university. Ask the graduate coordinator about the process.